# Toggling a boolean, i just dont get it

Tags: actionscript, menu, boolean, toggle

Im trying to create a menu. When i click on home, i want my home_text to fade in and when i click portfolio i want my home text to fadeout and my portfolio text to fade in:

```
 var home:Boolean = false;

 home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, homeButton_ON);
 function homeButton_ON(event: MouseEvent):void
 {
    home = true;
     display();
 }

 function display(event: MouseEvent):void
 {
     if (home = true)
     {
         TweenLite.to(home_text, 1, {alpha:1});
         TweenLite.to(portfolio_text, 1, {alpha:0});
     }
     else if (portfolio = true)
     {
        TweenLite.to(home_text, 1, {alpha:0});
        TweenLite.to(portfolio_text, 1, {alpha:1});
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Actionscript (like most, if not every, other language) requires a comparison to be `==` so your code is actually assigning.

Instead do:

```
 else if (portfolio == true)
```